# How can I get informed about the dynamic IP address of my computer?

Tags: windows-xp, ip

I have two PCs at home with two different Internet connections. I want to use a remote desktop connection, but my IP address is dynamic.

Is there any software I can install on Windows XP, which can solve my problem?

I tried Logmein, but it's not as easy as Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Any dynamic DNS provider should work.

Here's a fairly big list: http://www.inatech.eu/inadyn/dyndns_list.html

Some routers or router firmware (like [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29) and [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT)) provide dynamic DNS features, so it means you don't need to run the provider's dynamic DNS software on one of your local PCs.  Useful if you're NAT'ing several PCs.

Answer (score 2):

Get a free account on [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) and use their [Dyn Updater](http://dyn.com/support/clients/windows/)

> Features
>
> - Updates your DynDNS hostnames to resolve to your remote IP address
> - Full-featured, easy to use interface
> - Windows Service integration
> - Works on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows Server and Windows 7
> - Dyn Internet Guide setup assistance. Provides an option for
>     configuring Dyn Internet Guide on your Windows computer during
>     installation, enabling a better, faster, and safer Internet.
> - Maintains communication with Dyn to prevent Dynamic DNS hosts from
>     expiring due to inactivity
> - Logs activity to file, displays visual indicators of the Updater
>     status
> - Automatically determines which network interface to use,
>     automatically detects proxies
> - IP detection in real time (directly connected) or every 10 minutes
>     (behind a router/NAT)

Answer (score 1):

You can get free [sub]domains from [**no-ip.com**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), which you can use instead of IP addresses when connecting to your computers through RDP.

They have a [**DNS Update Client**](http://www.zoneedit.com/dynamicDNS.html), but many routers have the ability to send IP updates to `no-ip.com` and other [**DDNS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) providers.

If you already have your own domain, you may prefer to use [**ZoneEdit**](http://www.zoneedit.com/dynamicDNS.html), which is what I have been using for the last two or three years instead.

---

As the title of this question may bring other people here who are looking for something a bit different, this is a script I made to show your public IP address from the Windows command line (you need [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) for it to work):

```
@echo off

:: WhatIsMyIP.cmd

if [%1]==[-h] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[--help] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[/?] goto :HELP

wget -q -O %temp%\MyIP http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp
for /f "delims= " %%G in (%temp%\myip) do set PublicIP=%%G & del /q %temp%\MyIP
echo. & echo Your public IP address is %PublicIP%
if [%1]==[--clip] echo %PublicIP% | clip
goto :EOF

:HELP
echo. & echo Usage: whatismyip [--clip]
goto :EOF

:EOF
```